# TabIndex not working with nested smartgwt form

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

Tab index is not working as expected when there is nested canvas in the smartgwt dynamic form.

code:

```
DynamicForm form = new DynamicForm();

TextItem a = new TextItem("a", "A");
TextItem b = new TextItem("b", "B");

IButton ok = new IButton("ok");
IButton cancel = new IButton("cancel");

ToolbarItem btn= new ToolbarItem();
btn.setButtons(ok, cancel);

form.setItems(a, b, btn);
```

Tab index navigation : A -> B -> Ok -> A

Here the tab index is not locating the button 'Cancel', it is directly moving to Textbox A.

Answer (score 0):

You have a [couple of options](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwtee-latest/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/docs/TabOrderOverview.html), although I think the less work-intensive would be to mark specific items as "focusable". Other alternative would be to set specific tab indexes to your elements, but that is highly discouraged as it is very error prone.

This is the working code using setCanFocus:

```
DynamicForm form = new DynamicForm();

TextItem a = new TextItem("a", "A");
TextItem b = new TextItem("b", "B");

IButton ok = new IButton("ok");
ok.setCanFocus(true);
IButton cancel = new IButton("cancel");
cancel.setCanFocus(true);

ToolbarItem btn = new ToolbarItem();
btn.setButtons(ok, cancel);

form.setItems(a, b, btn);
form.show();
```